# AS3 How can i specify my textbox in other scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textbox, flash-cs5, scene

i want use that code;

```
username.text = amazing_text.text;
```

i try to work this code in my login screen class and normally this class dont see my changer password scene amazing_text. i try to work this main class but that create huge problem. and i wanna ask how can i specify "amazing_text" in the other scene ?

```
package actions {


import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.text.*;


public class main extends MovieClip {

    public function main ():void {



        submit_button.buttonMode = true;

        submit_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkLogin);

        username.text = "";
        password.text = "";

    }

    public function gotoscenetwo():void
    {
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1,"welcome");
    }






    public function checkLogin (e:MouseEvent):void {

        if (username.text == "" || password.text == "") {


            if (username.text == "") {

            username.text = "Enter your username";

            } 

            if (password.text == "") {

            password.text = "Enter your password";

            }

        } else {


            processLogin();


        }

    }

        public function processLogin ():void {


        var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

        var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("php/controlpanel.php");


        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

        var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;           
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);

        phpVars.systemCall = "checkLogin";
        phpVars.username = username.text;
        phpVars.password = password.text;

        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);




        }
    public function showResult (event:Event):void {

        result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT;
        result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;

        if(result_text.text == "undefined")
        {
        gotoscenetwo();
        username.text = amazing_text.text;
        }
        else{
        stop();
        }

        }
}
```

i cant add photo my reputation is low. but i can explain.

this is my website project
i have first login screen.
if user name and password correct
program go to welcome sceen and after that user can go to change password sceen.or browse my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it in some `variable` , then pass it to the next text field, like this:

```
public function showResult (event:Event):void {

    result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.RIGHT;
    result_text.text = "" + event.target.data.systemResult;

    if(result_text.text == "undefined")
    {
        var user_str:String = amazing_text.text;
        gotoscenetwo();
        username.text = user_str;
    } else{
        stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu it is another problem , it means you don't have a text field with a name `amazing_text`

Comment: no i have amazing_text.. but class not see my text because of that no main class symbol class

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu `result_text` field and `amazing_text` field are placed together? your class seeing the `result_text` but not seeing `amazing_text` ?

Comment: how can i specify amazing_text in my settings scene. my username in login scene. and that class in my login screen symbol class not main

Comment: yes that correct. not seeing amazing_text because this is in other scene. result_text and login text together

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu what goes first? the login scene is first and after comes settings scene?

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu can you please update your question with a full code of these classes?

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu after you went to a second stage , you still seeing the `username` field? or you just want to update its text without seeing it , so the next time you returning to the first scene `username` will be updated ?

Comment: i want see username in the update screen. because this is easy for update mysql for me, im beginner. i dont want bother any one again. if i can see my update screen username.text i can update myself.

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu so put a copy of `username` field also in "update screen" , and also call it `username`. there is no other way

Comment: ok i try that now can i change copy of username not changeable for text

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu what do you mean? if you don't want that user will be able to change it , so don't do it `input` type , only `dynamic`

Comment: thankyou so much. but i cant call `username.text` from other scene that my main problem.i copy `username` textbox from `login` screen and paste it `update` screen my `instance name` is same but `text` is not transport update screen.

Comment: @EcemAyhanoğlu try to get it in this way: `TextField( getChildByName( "username")).text = user_str;`